# Backspace inside INPUT element causes fixed position DIV to relocate to cursor

Tags: html, ios, cordova, input, webkit

Yeah.  Sounds weird.

I have a PhoneGap 2.1.0 app running on iOS6 (iPhone5), and unfortunately I cannot test on another device (I'll check simulator when I get home).

**Use case:**
User types text data into an INPUT element that spans beyond the visible width of the INPUT element, and must backspace to correct an error in typing.

**Expected:**
Last character is deleted.

**Actual:**
Last character is deleted, and *only if* the text deleted is beyond the visible bounds of the INPUT element, the "position:fixed;" application header relocates to the text input cursor's position.

**Here's a screen:** (sorry stack won't let me post imgs yet)
[issue screenshot](http://n2d.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/IMG_02372.png)

Anyone have any ideas?  If you need a specific portion of the HTML and/or CSS that renders this, let me know and I'll post it ASAP.

**Worthy to note:**

- The input elements have been re-skinned.
- The "-webkit-appearance" property is set to "none" for the input elements.
- This issue is consistent across ALL input elements (type=text, search, number, phone, or email), even ones in different forms/screens/pages.  I speculate this property has something to do with it - but I can't imagine what.  I've used this property in the past, with no issue.
- The backspace event functions as expected so long as the character being deleted in the input element does not reside beyond the visible bounds of the element.
- There are other fixed-position DIV elements in the site as well, but only the topnavbar/header is relocating.

Ideas?

Comment: This also happens in Chrome 23 - I haven't found a solution yet, but here's a thread discussing it: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139613

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This workaround works for me.

Add these to the affected inputs:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-transform-style: flat;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I added it to any text-based input elements via input[type="text"]{} and input[type="search"]{}

Comment: For me, just using `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` or `-webkit-perspective: 1000;` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can circumvent this using Jquery by hiding the header each time a backspace is pressed and then show it immediately after again.

```
$('#input_field').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 8) {
    return $('#header').hide(0, function() {
      return $(this).show();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My team had a similar issue with backspace in IOS6 + fixed header moving.  We couldn't find a real solution, but as a workaround we used modernizr to test for overflow content scrolling and applied position absolute to the header while applying the scrolling to the app-page div.

```
    Modernizr.addTest('overflowscrolling', function(){
            return Modernizr.testAllProps("overflowScrolling");
    });
```

css

```
.overflowscrolling .app-header {
   position: absolute;  
}

.overflowscrolling #app-page {
overflow: scroll;
position:absolute;
top:0px; 
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

}